# How has the return of a PHP-function to look like to be valid for use by AJAX and PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I got an input field. The user-input is getting checked on the fly by some AJAX request. The user is then getting informed whether his/her input is ok or not.

After submitting, the input has to be checked again for the same characteristics as it was checked before by AJAX(in case of JavaScript is deactivated).

AJAX uses "check.php" asynchronously.

```
<?php
include 'foo.php';
$input= $_POST['input'];

checkSomethingElse(testSomething($input));
?>
```

Then i got a "submit.php" file that is getting called on submission. It checks the input, and then writes the input into Database.

```
<?php
    include 'foo.php';
    $input= $_POST['input'];
    checkSomethingElse(testSomething($input));

foo(){
//write input into Database}
?>
```

The "foo.php" looks like this

```
<?php
function testSomething(){
//do something

}
function checkSomethingElse(){
//test...
echo value   // e.g. echo "true"
return value // e.g. return true

?>
```

(e.g. validate and sanitize input and other checks)

For the purpose of AJAX/JS/JQuery to use the returned value, it is returned trough "echo".

For the purpose of PHP to use the returned value, it is returned trough "return".

In case of AJAX-request there is everything fine, since it ignores the "return" and uses only "echo". In case of PHP it uses the "return value" and prints out the "echo value".

So the question is: 
Is this structure logically and functionally ok? And how can i fix this code to spit out a string trough the "echo", when the user is not using JavaScript?

Thank You.

Comment: I am surprised that `echo` works, seems the return would short-circuit that. Something I'd need to test.

Comment: of course it does not work, that was a typo, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate the display logic from the validation logic.

For example:

```
// validation functions
function testSomthing(){
    //test...
    return $value; // e.g. return true
}

function checkSomethingElse(){
    //test...
    return $value; // e.g. return true
}

// calling logic in check.php
include 'foo.php';
$result = false;
if (!empty($_POST['input']) {
    $input= $_POST['input'];
    $result = checkSomethingElse(testSomething($input));
}
$return = new stdClass();
$return->result = $result;
header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo json_encode($return);
```

Note: it is not clear from your example why you have nested validation function calls (i.e. `checkSomethingElse(testSomething($input))`).  I don't think it will work that way (because you will pass true/false result to outer function call), but I am showing the code here the same as you do, as I certainly don't have full picture as to function usage to offer up an alternative.

Comment: The nesting is just a bad translation of my code into a "simple to understand question" In the end only checkSomethingElse() is returning values, "testSomething()" is just for formatting/sanitizing the Input.

Comment: Could you please explain why i cant  use just"echo json_encode($result);" instead of "$return = new stdClass();
$return->result = $result;
header("Content-Type: application/json"); echo json_encode($return);"

Comment: @rave You can directly encode a true/false value, but you might get unexpected client behavior when trying to encode scalar type values depending on client and what version of JSON spec it supports.  For greater compatibility, I would suggest explicitly formulating an object or array wrapper around the scalar value - my personal preference being an object.

Answer (score 3):

first of all the first issue i can see is that you are calling echo after return ... which will never happen, because execution of the function ceases once it hits return.

I would suggest just making your functions that return a value and then determine if you need to echo it afterwards ...

```
<?php

  function some_function() {
    return "value";
  }

  $value = some_function();

  if (isset($_POST["returnajax"])) {
    echo $value;
  }

?>
```

as @rm-vanda suggests - json_encode may be useful to you if you are processing the AJAX request expecting a JSON. In this case it might look something like this...

```
function some_function() {
  return "value";
}
function some_other_function() {
  return "another_value";
}

$values = array();
$values[] = some_function();
$values[] = some_other_function();

if (isset($_POST["returnajax"])) {
  header("Content-Type: application/json");
  echo json_encode($values);
}
```

the resulting echo would look something like this:

```
["value","another_value"]
```

unfortunately, you may find that jquery will not like non well formed json. what i usually do is the following:

```
if (isset($_POST["returnajax"])) {
  header("Content-Type: application/json");
  echo json_encode(array("values"=>$values));
}
```

which would result in:

```
{"values":["value","another_value"]}
```

Comment: Why is array notation (`[ ... ]`) consider non-well formed in your mind?  That is totally fine JSON syntax, no need for object wrapper. Why would you ever manually build a JSON string?

Comment: i'm sure i've had issues in the past with jQueries' getJSON command not working when only an array was returned. perhaps i'm mistaken. As for manually building json ... its late - i will amend my code ... thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can check the variable $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    /* special ajax here echo for example*/
}
else {
  /* Not AJAX use return*/
}
```

Comment: It that case, would it make sense to include "check.php" into "submitt.php". Then check if the request is AJAX = execute only the check of input. If the request is actually the submission by the user = execute the submission? I mean would that cause better performance?

Comment: For me you can have only one file for both, you always return the value, and in if-else statement either you echo you value or do insert inside the db.
The if statement will be based like the one I wrote one my answer

Comment: This seems like a poor approach to solve the problem.  We already know the context of the request (i.e. AJAX or in-line code) based on the file from which the validation is being called.  You should remove display concerns to where the context is known and out of the validation functions altogether.